# なんか違うような help to understand

Tags: word-usage, phrases

Why in this phrase なんか　used with ような?

「な、なんか違うような……ううむ」

- なんか　- something like that
- ような　- like / similar to　（or よう　- way of doing, but then why な　is here?）

For me, this two words almost the same in meaning. I met this structure before, but still can't fully understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The less colloquial and more complete form is 何か違うような気がする, which means "I feel like something is odd" or "something is not quite right".

It's used in many situations, including when you want to point out somebody's unreasonableness in a polite way, e.g.:

> 「あなたの仕事じゃ無いけど、指摘してくれたのはあなたなんだから、あなたがやってよ」
> 「な、なんか違うような。。。でもまぁいいよ」